# Printing custom class object in Python without modifying class

Tags: python

I have a list of objects of Class A in Python. I cannot change/modify this class, and it does not implement a string method either.

I am debugging an application, therefore, I want to print contents each object of class A in the list.

Is there a way I can do this in Python?

I tried doing print(str(objA1)) but it just prints the reference and not the actual object.

Comment: You could just create some function that takes the object and it formats for you. `def format_custom(obj): return f"{obj.attr1} - {obj.attr2} - {obj.attr3}"` or however. You don't even need this to be a function, but that's the cleaner option.

Comment: Well, this class is complete opaque to me (somehow no documentation, legacy code), so I don't even know what attributes this class has. This is what I am trying to find/debug.

Comment: Get a object from the class and do `print(dir(obj))` on it. Unless they've overwritten that method, that should help. Also, if you load the load up the project in a IDE like Pycharm, you can do ctrl+B to go to the source of an object. Worst case scenario, you find the sript that defines the object on your computer and read it like any other file.